# Font spacing is very wide with Triplicate

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to test out a new font called Triplicate. When I try to use it each character is vary wide, like within a square, shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kt1U.jpg). Setting `variable-pitch-mode` doesn't change anything. I've not seen this problem with other fonts, and it does not have such wide spacing outside of Emacs, like in Abiword. It also looks good in OS X with the same Emacs configuration. Changing the width setting to condensed/compressed/normal/supercondensed/etc doesn't change the width at all.

I'm on Arch Linux, Emacs 25.4.1.

[image: Bad triplicate]

Comment: No, it doesn't look like that outside of emacs. I mentioned that I tried it in another application, I'll make an edit to make that more clear.  I'll certainly bear in mind that different fonts, indeed, can have different appearances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font developer found the issue and released an update to the font that fixes this issue!